# Обновление TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Программа выводит информацию о диске. Не могу понять, как обновлять данные TextBox, к примеру каждые 10 секунд, чтобы выводилась новая информация

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace laba2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getdrive();
        }

        private void getdrive()
        {
            string[] drive = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
            foreach (string item in drive)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString());

            }
        }
        private int _ticks;

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
            string getinfo = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            timer1.Start();
            DriveInfo drinfo = new DriveInfo(getinfo);

            double a = (drinfo.TotalSize) / 1073741824; //Объем диска в ГБ
            double b = (drinfo.TotalFreeSpace) / 1073741824; //Свободное пространство в ГБ
            double c = (drinfo.TotalSize - drinfo.TotalFreeSpace) / 1073741824; ; //Места занято в ГБ

//____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//

            string Disc_space= a.ToString(); 
            string Disc_free = b.ToString(); 
            string Disc_closed = c.ToString();

            textBox1.Text = "Размер диска: " + Disc_space + "ГБ";
            textBox2.Text = "Свободное пространство: " + Disc_free + "ГБ";
            textBox3.Text = "Места занято: " + Disc_closed + "ГБ";


        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` - у вас же есть обработчик `timer1_Tick`, пишите в нем код, который надо по таймеру выполнять.

Comment: Вынесите код из комбоксового обработчика в отдельный метод, вызывайте его из обоих обработчиков. Должно быть просто.